# SqlDataReader.Read return value interpretation

Tags: c#, sql, .net

The MSDN Documentation for the function `SqlDataReader.Read` says for the return type:

> true if there are more rows; otherwise false.

I find this formulation misleading, as it suggests that after `Read` has returned, at least 1 more row can be read, i.e. the next `Read` should be successful but return false.

In reality however, the return type represents what one would it expect to be, this is: "returns true if a row has been successfully read, false otherwise".

Is it just me or is the terminology chosen plain wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN [SqlDataReader.Read Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) states that Read method -

> Advances the SqlDataReader to the next record.

and returns

> true if there are more rows; otherwise false.

When SqlDataReader object is created, it does not point to the first record.  You need to call the Read method.  If the call is successful, the SqlDataReader object would point to the first record and return True.

Comment: This answer actually explains why the wording is in fact correct, thus accepted, thanks :)

Comment: @usr I accepted this answer, because it made clear to me that the `Read` function doesn't in fact read a row but prepares the Reader for reading it. (i.e. advancing the reading position to that row). Thus AFTER the function, the return value is true if there is at least one row to read, which doesn't necessarily mean, that Read can be successfully called another time. So maybe the function name isn't perfectly chosen...

Answer (score 1):

It does not suggest that is the condition after Read.
Taken literally yes you could make that interpretation.
Take it for what makes sense and the behavior you have observed.

It is the condition at the time the command is executed not the condition after the command.

When I read from the second to last row the condition is true.
And I get the last row.

Now I am on the last row and issue the command Read
At that point there are no more rows and the return value is false.

If it behaved as you suggest this would not read the last row

```
while (Reader.Read())
{
}
```